# Implementing a UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am looking to add a way to have a user search through my server for certain book titles. The user should be able to search using a string within a `UISearchBar`, and the results from the server should be displayed in a `UITableView` below the search bar. What would be the easiest way to implement something like this?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check the docs for UISearchDisplayController - does much of the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are exactly asking. Of course the moment something was entered in the UISearchBar your delegate method is called and you start in the background your client server communication and populate the table. Depends on how heavy the load is but I think for the best user experience you populate only a certain number of cells and the last cell is a "load more" to avoid long waiting.